# Chrome: element vanishes when using filter: brightness in column-layout

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-multicolumn-layout, css-filters

Today I've stumbled across a rather strange behaviour in google chrome (version 62.0.3202.94). It occurs when an element inside a column-layout is styled using `filter`. To be more specific: only when the element is not inside the first column. Here we go:

```css
.column-container {
  column-count: 2;
}

input[type="button"]:hover {
  filter: brightness(75%);
}
```

```html
<div class="column-container">
  <div class="col">
    <input type="button" value="Button1" />
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <input type="button" value="Button2" />
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, when hovering Button1 on the left side, it gets darker just as expected. But when hovering Button2 on the rigth side, it vanishes (becomes invisible). When working with `column-width` and resizing the window, so that the left column breaks under the right column, the hover effect on Button2 works as expected as well. All that also happens with other `filter` settings, eg. `blur`.

Two workarounds I found are:

- Using `background: hsla(0,0%,0%,0.25);`

  - this is not supported in all browsers
  - when used on a different background color, it just shines through because of the transparency
- Hack it via `transform: translateZ(0);` which triggers hardware acceleration

  - can be overwritten by later stylings

My questions are:

1. Why does that happen?
2. How do I make `filter` work **normally** for other columns than the first?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: can you specify the browser version. It works fine in Version 57.0.2987.133

Comment: I see the problem, but only when _clicking_ the button. Hovering is OK, but it goes invisible when I click.

Comment: I've noticed this same issue in Version 62.0.3202.94 (Official Build) (64-bit).  First column is fine, any other column doesn't work.  Thanks for the workarounds!

Comment: @YuPPie I've got version 62.0.3202.94 running.

Comment: @MrLister which version are you running?

Comment: @Akerus It happens that same way in different versions, including Chromium 57.0.2987.98 on Linux and the Canary 64.0.3281.0 on Windows. The left button is fine; it gets highlighted on hover; so does the right button, until I click on it, then it disappears.